# SceneKit: Error occur while rendering two SCNNodes with skeletal animations

Tags: swift, scenekit

I attempt to load skeletal animations with the following code:

```
let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "dae")
let source = SCNSceneSource(url: file!, options: nil)
let  node = SCNNode()
for n in try! (source?.scene(options: nil).rootNode.childNodes)! as [SCNNode] {
    node.addChildNode(n)
}
let animationIDs = source?.identifiersOfEntries(withClass: CAAnimation.self)
var animationArray:[CAAnimation] = []
for id in animationIDs!{
    let animation = source?.entryWithIdentifier(id, withClass: CAAnimation.self)
    animationArray.append(animation!)
}
let animationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
animationGroup.animations = animationArray
animationGroup.duration = 1000
animationGroup.repeatCount = 1000
animationGroup.beginTime = 0
node.addAnimation(animationGroup, forKey: "Animation")
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

At first it works successfully with the main hero node. The skeletal animation looks fine. But when I create enemies nodes, I receive the following error just after the game scene is loaded:

```
validateFunctionArguments:2665: failed assertion `(length - offset)(10992) must be >= 12304 at buffer binding at index 1 for scn_node[0].'
```

So what's wrong with it? It seems that I can still load other models without skeletal animations, and these animations can still run perfectly. But does it mean that SceneKit only allows us to load skeletal animations on one specific SCNNode?

If you know something about that error, please help me solve that...
And if you have better solutions on how to load skeletal animations from dae files, please share...
Thanks you very much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be an error in SceneKit, or a false positive from the Metal Validation Layer.

You can try to [disable the validation layer in your scheme options](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Dev-Technique/Dev-Technique.html) or try to open your app outside of Xcode to see if skeletal animation works properly and if the error is not relevant.